# PySpark Error FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to run pyspark code in jupyter notebook using python 3 (ipykernel).
Last time, pyspark was working well but after redownloading the new pyspark hadoop file to 3.3.2, somehow i can not run anything. I dont remember what was last version.

Original code

`import findspark`

`from pyspark.sql.functions import lit`

`from pyspark.sql.functions import col`

`from pyspark.conf import SparkConf`

`findspark.init()`

`import pyspark` 
`from pyspark.sql import SparkSession`

`conf = SparkConf().setAppName("A2").set("spark.driver.memory", "8g").set("spark.executor.memory", "8g")`

Error code

`spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()`

`spark`

The first linewith bilder.config causes error as below :

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
    ~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_17812\1018616192.py in <module>
    ----> 1 spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
      2 spark
    
    ** ..... omitted **


    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I tried to reset variable and path environments as below but my jupyter still can not find the pyspark or even python. How can I fix this error?

`import os print(os.environ.get("SPARK_HOME")) print(os.path.join(os.environ.get("SPARK_HOME"), './bin/spark-submit.cmd'))`

Output:
C:\spark\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop2
C:\spark\spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop2./bin/spark-submit.cmd

My environment is like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvOgC.png)

Comment: I don't think HADOOP_HOME and SPARK_HOME should be the same values. You also need to update `winutils.exe` to use Hadoop3.3.2 if you haven't ... Or, just use WSL2 (a Linux environment) instead of Windows host

Comment: Was the solution to this error found? I have been facing this issue since yesterday.