# Trouble finding the required Java components for Pyspark on JupyterLab

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, compiler-errors

I know this questions has been solved on other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75522464/pyspark-error-filenotfounderror-winerror-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-sp). However, even if I followed the solutions from others post, I’m not able to solve it for my case.

Two days ago, I download and Installed PySpark on my Jupyterlab environment. Now, when I tried to create a Spark Session I received the FileNotFoundError: [WinError2] The system cannot find the file specified.

This is my original code

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('practice').getOrCreate()
```

Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 2
      1 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
----> 2 spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('practice').getOrCreate()

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I tried to modify SPARK_HOME, JAVA_HOME, and PATH, but this didn’t solve my problem.

```
import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "C:\Java"
os.environ["PATH"] = "C:\Java\bin;" 
spark_home_bin = "C:\spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3 (1)\spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3\bin"
os.environ['PATH'] = spark_home_bin + ";" + os.environ["PATH"]
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "C:\spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3 (1)\spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3\bin"
```

I also tried to uninstall and reinstall everything (Java, Spark, and Anaconda). My current version of these programs are:

- Java: version 1.8.0_391
- Apache Spark 3.0.5
- Apache, package type: pre-built for apache Hadoop 3.3 and later, or pre-built with user-provided apache hadoop

My environment is like this
[Environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh6kO.png)

I appreciate any advise about what I've missed here.

I tried, the followings:

1. Download older versions of Java, because other users suggest versions 8 and 11 for compatibility reasons.
2. Uninstall and reinstall everything
3. Update 'PATH' variables in the "Environment variables"
4. Restart Jupyter Kernel each type the 'PATH' variable was updated

**EDIT:**
I had an error in the Spark_home path, the correct typo is:

```
 os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "C:\spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3\spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3"
```

note: I also change the name of my spark file, to remove spaces and the (1) I had. Now, the error I get is:

```
PySparkRuntimeError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 2
      1 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
----> 2 spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('practice').getOrCreate()
...
PySparkRuntimeError: [JAVA_GATEWAY_EXITED] Java gateway process exited before sending its port number.
```

Answer (score 0):

Spark can only work with files in Hadoop. You are setting environment variable in local windows machine.
You need to set bin path in HDFS.